# Better workflow of Svg's​ for web

Tags: adobe-photoshop, svg

What is the best way to bring svg's from Photoshop to web using @font-face?

Comment: Export it and use @font-face, what exactly do you want to know? As it is your question is quite broad and it might be closed.

Comment: Sorry, if I don't get my question. I want to export font-face icons as svg and being editable for web

Answer (score 1):

I always found [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) to be a great resource for creating vector icon font sets, assuming that's what you are looking for considering the mention of @font-face.

Comment: By doing this way, do we have a ability to edit this using css